# Why is my case statement failing despite the condition being true?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a kata that tallies scores based on the role of five six sided die. Here is my code so far:

```
def score( dice )
    points = []
    score = {}
    dice.each do |n|
      if score.has_key?(n.to_s.to_sym)
        score[n.to_s.to_sym] += 1
      else
        score[n.to_s.to_sym] = 1
      end
    end

    score.each do |k,v|
      key_int = k.to_s.to_i

      case key_int
      when key_int == 1 && (v == 3)
        points << 1000
      when key_int == 6 && (v == 3)
        points << 600
      when key_int == 5 && (v == 3)
        points << 500
      when key_int == 4 && (v == 3)
        points << 400
      when key_int == 3 && (v == 2)
        points << 300
      when key_int == 2 && (v == 3)
        puts "did I get here"
      points << 200
      when key_int == 1 && (v < 3)
        points << key_int * v
      when key_int == 5 && (v < 3)
        points << key_int * v
      else
      puts "Default"
    end
  end
  points
end

puts score([2, 2, 2, 3, 3]) ==> 200
```

So at a basic level for this example, what's happening is when my each loop hits the hash I get this condition of:

```
key_int == 2 && (v == 3)
```

and insert it into the code before the case statement, I get a value of `true` but I never reach the condition of `points << 200`. For simplification I whittled down the code to this for the case logic.

```
score.each do |k,v|
  key_int = k.to_s.to_i
  case key_int
  when key_int == 2
    puts "I reached the condition"
  else
    puts "default"
  end
end
```

I still get the default and I never reach the `when` condition. This is confusing me. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use `case` instead of `case key_int`.

Comment: Did I miss something? This blog told me otherwise http://blog.honeybadger.io/rubys-case-statement-advanced-techniques/

Comment: The blog post uses a lambda and a custom matcher class to compare via `==` and `<`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify an object right after `case`, it will be compared against each `when` pattern via `pattern === object`.

In this example:

```
case key_int
when key_int == 2
  # ...
end
```

it will compare `key_int`  against `key_int == 2` like this:

```
(key_int == 2) === key_int
```

Assuming that `key_int` is `2`, the above becomes:

```
true === 2
```

which evaluates to `false`.

To use a `case` expression like an `if-elsif` expression, you have to omit the initial object:

```
case
when key_int == 2
  # ...
end
```

See Ruby's documentation on the  [`case` Expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) for another example.